# Is there a way to give order field to the result of MongoDB aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Is there any way to give order or rankings to MongoDB aggregation results?

My result is:

```json
{
  "score":100
  "name": "John"
},
{
  "score":80
  "name": "Jane"
},
{
  "score":60
  "name": "Lee"
}
```

My wanted result is:

```json
{
  "score":100
  "name": "John",
  "rank": 1
},
{
  "score":80
  "name": "Jane"
  "rank": 2
},
{
  "score":60
  "name": "Lee"
  "rank": 3
}
```

I know there is a operator called `$includeArrayIndex` but this only works with `$unwind` operator.
Is there any way to give rank without using `$unwind`?

Using `$unwind` requires grouping on my collection, and I'm afraid grouping pipeline would be too huge to process.

Comment: Like this `var count = 1; db.meow.aggregate(yourPipeline).forEach( doc=>{   doc.rank=count; count++; printjson(doc) })` ?

Comment: I think this would work in mongo cli or js project. But I am using Spring framework's driver so I wanted to know how to handle this at aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

The other way is to use `$map` and add rank in document using its index, and don't use `$unwind` stage because it would be single field array you can directly access using its key name as mention in last line of code,

- `$group` by null and make array of documents in `root` array,
- `$map` to iterate loop of `root` array, get the index of current object from root array using `$indexOfArray` and increment that returned index number using `$add` because index start from 0, and that is how we are creating `rank` field, merge object with current element object and `rank` field using `$mergeObjects`

```
let result = await db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      root: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      root: {
        $map: {
          input: "$root",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                rank: { $add: [{ $indexOfArray: ["$root", "$$this"] }, 1] }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);

// you can access result using root key
let finalResult = result[0]['root'];
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3kUvBTrQNKa)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your idea. But I am worried about `$group` pipeline might be too huge

Comment: If you are sure your return data would be more than 16 MB then i can say its huge, so 
 you have to go with other option, and there is no any other option to add ordered field in document without this stages except these two, you have to do this in client side. you can use this trick if you are sure your combine document in group would be under 16MB than you can use this,